# How exactly DateFormat.parse(String) treats non-date trailing text?

Tags: java, date

Parse method of `DateFormat` class is expected to *ignore trailing text* if it succeeds to parse a date from the beginning of a String.

API [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) are evasive:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
>   The method *may* not use the entire text of the given string.

I thought "may" means - "if trailing text exists and is not part of the date (cannot be interpreted as such)". But looks like this "may" is much more unpredictable.

Given

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This works incorrectly (unexpectedly):

```
System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-112"));

Output: Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 MSK 2020
```

While this works OK (as expected):

```
System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-11sometext"));

Output: Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 MSK 2019
```

If the rest of parsed text is digits, it seems to always fail to parse correctly (giving different erroneous results):

```
System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-1189"));
System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-11234"));

Output: 
Fri Mar 03 00:00:00 MSK 2023
Fri Sep 02 00:00:00 MSK 2050
```

Now, `setLenient()` behaves like this:

1. *If (correct) date is followed by a space or letters, then setLenient() setting makes no difference*. Everything is parsed correctly and without exceptions for both setLenient (true/false).
2. But *if (correct) date is immediately followed by digit(s) then setLenient() does make (unexpected) difference*: default (true) produces no exception and wrong (!) parse result, but setLenient(false) woud result in `ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-12-111"` which is also strange (the date is correct and ignoring trailing text was kind-of promised by the API)...

`Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos)` behaves absolutely identically to `Date parse(String source)` in all the above cases (including reaction to setLenient) for the only (and expected) exception that where one-arg *parse()* throws *ParseException*, this two-arg *parse()* returns *null* (which is its reaction to incorrect date format at the beginning of String to parse).

Also worth noting that after calling `mydateFormat.parse("2019-12-11234", pos)` (with *setLenient(true)*), `pos.getIndex()` returns 13 - which points "beyond" 234 part, meaning *it treats this 234 part as "-dd" part of "yyyy-MM-dd" in `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`*.

P.S. I know that these are outdated date/time API and I shall prefer java.time over Date/Calendar/DateFormat etc. But it is still massively present in legacy code to support in cases where refactoring is not an option.

Comment: Try to call `setLenient(false)`, see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

When you set isLenient to true and adds extra number the formatter will try to calculate a new date from the given values so `df.parse("2019-12-1189")` will be parsed as 2019-12-01 + 1189 days (1189/365 = 3.26) so *Fri Mar 03 00:00:00 MSK 2023* looks like the correct result (I don't know the exact math here).

Same for 11234 that adds roughly 30 years.

You could also try this for 2019-12-32 and 2019-13-01 which both gets converted to 2020-01-01

Comment: I think the question is more about how to force `SimpleDateFormat` to obey the provided pattern even if trailing numbers are given as input, as  - apparently - `setLenient(false)` does not.

Comment: Yeah, this question seems have been updated a few times. I might have had an old version loaded when answering this

Answer (score 0):

Two points.

1. Even though you’ve said it yourself already, I want to reiterate, *don’t* use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s notoriously troublesome and long outdated.
2. Your quote from the documentation needs to be read in conjunction with at least one other point from there. Basically there is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can do what you had wanted it to do.

### java.time

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
            .parse("2019-12-112", new ParsePosition(0)));
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2019-12-11

I think this is the result that you wanted. `2019-12-11` has been parsed as the date and `2` has been ignored as trailing text, not part of the date.

### You cannot do it with SimpleDateFormat

To make my point here I am using a different example:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    df.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-013"));
```

> Fri Dec 13 00:00:00 CET 2019

This behaviour *is* documented. In addition to your quote we need to read:

> - **Number:** … For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

So in my example, since there isn’t any adjacent field after `dd`, there is no way that we can persuade `SimpleDateFormat` to read `013` as anything else than the number 13.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` internally uses (a locale specific) instance of `NumberFormat` to parse the given date. In my case it is an instance of `DecimalFormat`.

Debugging `SimpleDateFormat` reveals that the crucial part in is this:

```
if (obeyCount) {
    if ((start+count) > text.length()) {
        break parsing;
    }
    number = numberFormat.parse(text.substring(0, start+count), pos);
} else {
    number = numberFormat.parse(text, pos);
}
```

Given your first example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(df.parse("2019-12-112"));
```

the internally set `obeyCount` is `false`, so `numberFormat.parse()` is always called on the whole part of text: `112`. The same happens with this example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(df.parse("201912112"));
```

I would consider at least the latter example as a possible bug. But the logic of setting `obeyCount` is that complicated that I don't feel it's worth any deeper exploring (as this API is somewhat out-dated).

Also note that `setLenient(boolean)` does not modify the internal `NumberFormat` parser but just the `Calendar` instance which comes into play after parsing is done. For the rest, see answer by Joakim Danielson.